# Can't install SSL Certificate from Visual Studio 2017, access denied

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, ssl-certificate

I have created a dotnet Core project in Visual Studio. When I try to execute the program, Visual Studio prompts me to trust the SSL certificate of IIS Express to avoid warnings in the navigator. When I press "yes", an alert appears stating

> failed to add the certificate to the certificate store of trusted root certifications. Error :
>   Access denied.

The list of things that I have tried:

- Execute Visual Studio as Administrator
- Put the certificate from personal certificates to Trusted Root Certification Authorities ( as "local computer" and "my computer account" )

Comment: Although it is a discussion about docker issues there are several proposals to solve this error [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/99)
Another resource could also be the following blog entry [hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopingLocallyWithASPNETCoreUnderHTTPSSSLAndSelfSignedCerts.aspx)

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly the admin privilege execution does, but the insert of certification must be done via other program (technically, **Visual Studio** executes app **<certmgr>**, which will perform the insert). Try to log in as an administrator to perform this action, it might give you required privileges.